# Fastest way to bulk insert from a text file to sql server without integration services

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following requirement

The customer will put a file on a folder which can be worth 600MB size,  I need with a Windows Service to poll the folder, once a new file is dropped there, then I need to process it and insert into SQL Server.

What would be the fastest way recommended?  ADO.NET with an INSERT per row?  what would you recommend me?

Comment: Use a [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx), team that up with a custom `IDataReader` that accesses your file with custom processing ...

Comment: You could also try [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bulk insert feature of SQL server.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhilsi/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ADO.NET, but don't INSERT per row. That can be incredibly taxing if you have 600MB of rows in a text file.  Instead, create a User Defined Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTable] AS TABLE
(
    [Col1] INT NOT NULL,
    [Col2] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [Col3] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
)
```

Then in C# create a Data Table.

```
var dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
```

Load it using this syntax.

```
dt.Rows.Add(someVar1, someVar2, someVar3);
```

Load the data table in batches, and then submit the data table as a parameter to SQL like any other parameter.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Values", Value = dt });
```

Your stored procedure should be expecting the parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ive].[myProc]
@Values [dbo].[MyTable] READONLY
```

Then simply use it in your stored procedure like a table. You can wrap the process in a transaction in case a bulk insert fails at any step, and use some other logic to correct the issue.